# Why createUserWithEmailAndPassword set my current user variable (getCurrentUser())?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my google authenticate activity:

```
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(GoogleAuthentication.this, ChatRoomActvity.class));
    } else {
        googleSignIn();
    }
}
```

Then I have a register activity for users who want to signup with email and pass. Here is a code snippet:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            mProgress.dismiss();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Task not successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Login screen has 2 options 
 1. google login
 2. signup

Problem is when a user choose #2 say signup, he enters user/pass and the `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` adds this user/pass to firebase auth db and it also sets this user as a current user. I don't know why it sets the user as a current user, i just called `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` not `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

Now after playing with option#2, when user goes back to #1, he logs in directly to chatroom activity because 
`firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null`.

Basically I want the firebase `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` should not set my current user variable. 
`firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` should be `null`, until I call `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

Comment: qbix's answer has the right of it: creating a user automatically signs that user in. You could potentially immediately sign the user out again. But to be honest: making the user immediately re-enter their credentials sounds like a suboptimal user experience to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to rethink your design. The documentation for [createUserWithEmailAndPassword()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) explains that the method:

> Tries to create a new user account with the given email address and
>   password. If successful, it also signs the user in into the app

Comment: cool, I kind of stored the state in Db everytime I login....
So now before login i check the state along with getcurrentUser.. which help me making better decision if user just did signup or actually signed in :) thanks